# Change addresses in old backups

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, wallet.dat, change

I have a very old wallet backup, from 2011, from bitcoin-qt, I imported it to bitcoin core, but I seem to have only one address, seems that I have no change addresses in the imported data.
Is the current bitcoin core importing wallets partially?
Did bitcoin-qt at 2011 create change addresses in a different way?
I searched, but the info I found mainly relates to much newer versions of wallets than the ones bitcoin-qt used.
Update: using pywallet I managed to get the additional 102 addresses in the wallet, and import them, now I'm doing a rescan.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Only very, very early Bitcoin clients didn't create change addresses automatically.</strike>

In 2011, <strike>change addresses were automatic, but</strike> the address pool was only 100 addresses long (more frequent backups were needed). It was some years later it was increased to 1000 and Hierarchical Deterministic was invented.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the Bitcoin Core wallet always created change addresses (including before it was called that way) since version 0.1..